# How would I go about listing all BTC addresses that have the substring "XYZ" appearing in their address?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I need to list ALL BTC addresses that have the substring "XYZ" appearing in their address. How would I go about doing this ?

I do not have much experience with blockchain and any programming language that could achieve it would be good for me.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "All addresses". If someone creates an address, but no Bitcoin have been sent to it, then there is no way to know it exists unless that person tells you.

If you mean any address which has been sent Bitcoin, then you have to either scan the entire blockchain and encode all scriptPubKeys in every transaction and store it in a searchable database. You could use a service like a block explorer which has already done this, to search for addresses with that substring, but that will probably be an expensive search which might not be possible, because APIs don't typically allow for that type of search.

I would recommend getting a block explorer running locally and then implement your own query using the local transaction database. This will take a while to sync and index the entire blockchain by address.